# use sed to replace a specific string with slashes

Tags: linux, sed

I have a big text file -a windows registry file- about 5.5MB and I have to remove a string "serv\b\Param\". Opening with gedit or nano doesn't work. It will either consume 100% cpu time for some unreasonable long amount of time or it will just print random garbage of text. I tried using these commands from linux because I can't use the other one:

```
sed -i 's|"serv\b\Param"|""|g' ~/Desktop/3.reg

sed -i 's|\"serv\b\Param"|\""|g' ~/Desktop/3.reg

sed -i 's:serv\b\Param:"":g' ~/Desktop/3.reg

sed -i 's:serv\b\Param::g' ~/Desktop/3.reg

sed -i 's:"serv\b\Param":"":g' ~/Desktop/3.reg
```

Nothing work so far.
What is wrong with these commands?

Comment: In `"serv\b\Param\"`, are those quotes and the three backslashes literal characters in the file?  Or, where they added to represent  something else?

Comment: No, its just  serv\b\Param\  and there is no quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The slashes need to be escaped:

```
sed -i 's|serv\\b\\Param\\||g' ~/Desktop/3.reg
```

In `sed`, a single backslash is usually a escape character for something.  For example, in GNU `sed`, an escape-b, as in `\b`, is interpreted to mean a word boundary.  To prevent such interpretation, place two backslashes in a row where ever you want to match a single literal backslash.

#### Example

Based on your sample (updated as per the comments), let's start with this file:

```
$ cat 3.reg
serv\b\Param\
abc serv\b\Param\ def
```

Applying the above `sed` command:

```
$ sed -i 's|serv\\b\\Param\\||g' 3.reg
$ cat 3.reg

abc  def
```

The pattern is successfully removed.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that `\` introduces various sequences in regular expressions, so to match `\` in the input stream you need to use `\\` in the RE.

It is not clear whether the quotes are part of the string you want to remove: from your fourth example I would assume not, in which case this example works if you double the back-slashes:

```
sed -i 's:serv\\b\\Param::g' ~/Desktop/3.reg
```

You do not need double-quotes in the search or replacement strings unless they form part of the search criteria: the single-quotes around the edit expression already remove any special meanings as far as the shell is concerned, so `sed` sees the literal expression.